# Including assets and locales into gem Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have smth like this in my Gemfile

```
gem 'plugin', :git => 'git://plugin.git'
```

And I want to add some assets and locales in my plugin, so I have to add pathes into Rails::Engine config. So I have smth like this in my init.rb

```
I18n.load_path += Dir[File.join(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)), 'locales', '*.yml')]
Rails.application.class.config.assets.paths << File.join(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)), 'assets')
```

And this works fine for locales, but not so I have an exception for assets (Rails.application.class.config is nil). So what is right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank @phoet for the link. I look throw the code from his link and found this

```
module JqueryMobileRails
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  end
end
```

So I added this to lib/my_plugin.rb

```
module MyPlugin
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  end
end
```

And it works!

Comment: took me hours to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you need to mess around with the rails paths?

i think that you can use convention over configuration and just put your assets into `lib/assets` or `vendor/assets` and they will get loaded automagically.

have a look at the docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

Comment: But what if I want to have assets in my bundle/plugin/lib/assets dir?

Comment: I have a plugin. This plugin have some ruby code and some javascript code. So I want somehow include this javascript code into my app.

Comment: And I don't really understand why rails doesn't include /lib/assets/* and /lib/config/locales/* by default from gems.

Comment: i think that `vendor/assets` would be the correct place to put them. see the jquery-mobile-rails plugin https://github.com/tscolari/jquery-mobile-rails